# nested for loop optimisation

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, time-complexity

I have this expression

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < expression.size(); i++){
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < expression.size(); j++){
        result += (expression.at(j) - expression.at(i));
    }
    result += (g - expression.at(i));
}
return result;
```

in the vector expression we have for example [1,2,3].  I am trying to get something like:

```
f1=[(2-1)+(3-1)]
r1 = g-1
h1 = r1+f1

f2=[3-2]
r2 = g-2
h2 = r2+f2

f3 = 0
r3 = g-3
h3 = r3+f3

then h1+h2+h3
```

What i am doing right now is in Θ(n^2).  Is there a way to make it faster even without for loops?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in O(n). Look at how many times you add and subtract each element.

Comment: @Beta edited i made a mistake, but i still don't know how to get it to O(n).

Comment: Suppose the vector is `[a, b, c, d, e]`. What is the result? See a pattern?

Comment: @Beta [a, b, c, d, e] the result would be: `first = ((b-a)+(c-a)+(d-a)+(e-a))  then (h= g-a)  then (f=h+first)` , `second = (((c-b)+(d-b)+(e-b))  then (h2= g-b)  then (f2=h2+second)` and so on which is what the code at the beginning is doing, but a pattern to get to O(n) i don't really see it.

Comment: @milkyway What is `g`? You can calculate it in `O(n)` by simply grouping the terms, but the overflow conditions will be different, in case your values are approaching that range.

Comment: @dxiv g is like a maximum that i chose. i made a mistake on the operation 'r2 = g-2'. can you show me an example of how to group them? i have been stuck on this for so long.

Comment: @dxiv i still don't now how.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont how to make it to O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition is commutative and associative so the operations can be reordered and grouped without changing the final result. (*Note: not taking into account possible overflows in the intermediate calculations, which may be affected by the order and grouping of operations*.)

In pseudo-code with `n = expression.size()` and `x[k] = expression.at(k)` the original code can be broken down as follows, with the intermediate results indicated in comments.

```
a = b = c = d = 0

for i = 0 to (n-1)
    for j = (i+1) to (n-1)
        a += x[j]
    // == x[i+1] + x[i+2] + ... x[n-1]
// a == 0 * x[0] + 1 * x[1] + 2 * x[2] + 3 * x[3] + ... + (n-1) * x[n-1]

for i = 0 to (n-1)
    for j = (i+1) to (n-1)
        b += x[i];
    // == (n-i-1) * x[i]
// b == (n-1) * x[0] + (n-2) * x[1] + ... + 2 * x[n-3] + 1 * x[n-2]

for i = 0 to (n-1)
    c += g
// c == n * g

for i = 0 to (n-1)
    d += expression.at(i))
// d == x[0] + x[1] + ... + x[n-1]

result = c     + a      - b     - d
       = n * g
               + (0     - (n-1) - 1) * x[0]
               + (1     - (n-2) - 1) * x[1]
               + ...
               + ((n-2) - 1     - 1) * x[n-2]
               + ((n-1) - 0     - 1) * x[n-1]
```

The latter `result` can be calculated directly from that formula, with one single `O(n)` loop.